# Instagram API: The access_token provided is invalid

Tags: instagram-api

I have registred a sandbox user. Now I am trying to use it, but I recieve "The access_token provided is invalid". 
Sample request:

[https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/searchq=abc&count=2&client_id=7b67cff1a7ab462881298434c08b5ab8](https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?q=abc&count=2&client_id=7b67cff1a7ab462881298434c08b5ab8)

It was working in live mode, but I can't find why it isn't working in sandbox.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to  check for **requirements [Scope for AP](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/)I** you are using and if it's need and Authentications "Valid access Token". where also had some changes.

- basic - to read a user’s profile info and media
- public_content  to read any public profile info and media on a user’s behalf
- follower_list  to read the list of followers and followed-by users
- comments - to post and delete comments on a user’s behalf
- relationships - to follow and unfollow accounts on a user’s behalf
- likes - to like and unlike media on a user’s behalf

**And take look about **Sandbox API behavior**  of your application not **life** yet :**

**API Behavior**

The behavior of the API when you are in sandbox mode is the same as when your app is live, but comes with the following restrictions:

Data is restricted to sandbox users and the 20 most recent media from each sandbox user
Reduced API rate limits
The first point is important and it means that the API behaves as if the only users on Instagram were your sandbox users, and the only media ever posted were the last 20 for each of these users.

For example, if you query the /users/{user-id}/ endpoint and the {user-id} is a sandbox user, then you will get the normal API response; but if the {user-id} is not a sandbox user, you will get a APINotFound error.

Good luck

Answer (score 5):

For me the access token Instagram generate is too short: they gave me something like this:

d2c387d768ec4d619306807c53bbf92b

it should be:

2940736713.1677ed0.31bb22b2b0f84befacc79c6afd025134

I used this site to generate it:
http://instagram.pixelunion.net

Comment: d2c387d768ec4d619306807c53bbf92b is client id. To generate the access token use the below link: https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT-ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT-URI&response_type=token

Comment: Worked for me!  Why IG would they generate the wrong tho?

Comment: {"error_type": "OAuthException", "code": 400, "error_message": "Invalid response type: token"}

Answer (score 4):

I found it when solving the same problem with access by access_token

Here is official faq how to get access_token

You just should go through following steps (link to Instagram API documentation https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/):

**1.Request the CODE**

```
https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT-ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT-URI&response_type=code
```

change CLIENT_ID to you client id (you could get it here https://www.instagram.com/developer/clients/manage/ )

change REDIRECT-URI to your redirect_uri from tab security in client settings(open link above and tap to 'manage' button). I Used this one https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/ Encode url here and paste te result instead REDIRECT-URI

After you prepared it cope ready link to adress bar in your browser and run

**2. Get the CODE**

Browser ask you a premissons and redirect you to callback url with the code in the end. It will be look like this in adress bar:

```
http://yoursite.some/?code=d8af5619af6853d4ad11b4dd5f1ef17e
```

In this example your code is **d8af5619af6853d4ad11b4dd5f1ef17e**
Save it. You should use it in access_token request below

**3. Make an access_token request**

Open terminal and use curl:

```
curl -F 'client_id=CLIENT_ID' \
-F 'client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET' \
-F 'grant_type=authorization_code' \
-F 'redirect_uri=AUTHORIZATION_REDIRECT_URI' \
-F 'code=CODE' \
https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token
```

Change CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, AUTHORIZATION_REDIRECT_URI and CODE to your own data and run it.

Curl return you JSON with access_token like this:

```
{
    "access_token": "fb2e77d.47a0473320504cb3ab4a1f626d174d2d",
    "user": {
        "id": "1576583",
        "username": "some",
        "full_name": "Some",
        "profile_picture": "..."
    }
}
```

Well done! In this example **fb2e77d.47a0473320504cb3ab4a1f626d174d2d** is your access_token. Copy access_token value, use it in your app and enjoy you coding! :)

Comment: Hey @Aleksey, Can you please look into this once: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59052304/oauthaccesstokenexception-the-access-token-provided-is-invalid-instagram-new-api

Comment: @user2028 Hi! I should try it again because I forgot this experience. But in your post somebody answered about instagram API deprecation. I think that could be right. When I posted this comment it was the transition period from old Instagram api to new version. However if it will be helpful I can create an Android App from scratch a try it to connect with the new instagram api. Feel free to write me a message if you are not solved this issue. I'll try to help you.

Comment: How to do in instagram graph API? Can you please tell me? It's return same error.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was using v1 of [Instafeed.js](https://github.com/stevenschobert/instafeed.js), rather than v2.

Once I switched to v2, everything started working.

```
<script src="/instafeed/dist/instafeed.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ig.instant-tokens.com/users/.../instagram/.../token.js?userSecret=..."></script>
<div id="instafeed" class="instagram-feed">

</div>
<script>
    (function(){
      console.log(InstagramToken);
      window.addEventListener('load', function () {
        var feed = new Instafeed({
          accessToken: InstagramToken,
        });
        feed.run();
      });
    })();
</script>
```

Answer (score -3):

You haven't specified an access_token for your request.