# The access_token provided is invalid. Instagram

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I've referred to this question [Instagram API: The access_token provided is invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37609974/instagram-api-the-access-token-provided-is-invalid), before posting this question myself.

My situation is quite similar, where I've just registered a new app yesterday, and it is now in Sandbox mode. I do understand that my access to instagram data is quite limited. However I've got no idea why even the simplest of request as below, I received error `The access_token provided is invalid.`

https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN

I'm quite certain that I'm doing this right, however just in case I'm doing it wrong. First I will need to login to my app with the below URL, where I would need to change to my own `CLIENT-ID` and `REDIRECT-URI`.

https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT-ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT-URI&response_type=code

Upon successful login, it will redirect to my `REDIRECT-URI` example: http://your-redirect-uri?code=CODE

I copy the generated `CODE` and append with https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/?access_token=CODE, which it is returning me with `The access_token provided is invalid.`

Please correct me if I'm doing it wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For those who faced the same issue as me, I realised that I needed to change `code` to `access-token`. Because I'm using Implicit flow, I needed to change that parameter to return me a token.

From: 
https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT-ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT-URI&response_type=**code**

To: https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT-ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT-URI&response_type=**token**

Comment: By the way, remember to unset Disable implicit OAuth option in IG Manage Clients Console.

Comment: Wow, thank you for this! was driving me insane why my "token" wasn't working.