# How to get Instagram Profile Picture?

Tags: java, android, json, instagram, instagram-api

How to extract Instagram Profile picture using instagram API in android ?
Or any other Method To extract Insta Profile Picture?

Answer (score 49):

By May 2023, to get Instagram profile URL via API, use this:

https://www.instagram.com/USERNAME/?__a=1&__d=1

Comment: It is not giving me data if I am not logged into Instagram

Comment: @ShrijanRegmi sometimes you need to specify some headers like User-Agent. Eg. `curl -s -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 12_3_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/15E148 Instagram 105.0.0.11.118 (iPhone11,8; iOS 12_3_1; en_US; en-US; scale=2.00; 828x1792; 165586599)' 'https://www.instagram.com/USERNAME/?__a=1'`

Comment: Neither of these appear to work anymore as of Sep 10, 2021. Perhaps instructions are missing from the answer but more likely instagram has disallowed these APIs

Comment: https://www.instagram.com/USERNAME/?__a=1  This is not working in my app. This link returns as error HTML code,

Comment: as of recently instagram doesn't allow the use of the public API, I've tried it for multiple times all it returns is a redirect to the actual profile

Comment: use https://www.instagram.com/<insta-username>/?__a=1&__d=1, it should work.

Comment: The currently latest noted answer https://www.instagram.com/USERNAME/?__a=1&__d=1 does not work for me since it blocks my access via server. It seems to be a CORS limit blocking data access from other servers (including Postman).

Comment: OK, perhaps not CORS but it requires a token. It says `{"message":"Please wait a few minutes before you try again.","require_login":true,"status":"fail"}` so probably a valid Instagram access token is required.

Answer (score 14):

To get profile photo, use the function bellow:

```js
function getPhoto(a) {
  
  // validation for instagram usernames
  var regex = new RegExp(/^(?!.*\.\.)(?!.*\.$)[^\W][\w.]{0,29}$/);
  var validation = regex.test(a);

  if(validation) {
  
    $.get("https://www.instagram.com/"+a+"/?__a=1")
    .done(function(data) { 

      // getting the url
      var photoURL = data["graphql"]["user"]["profile_pic_url_hd"];

      // update img element
      $("#photoReturn").attr("src",photoURL)
     
     })
    .fail(function() { 
      // code for 404 error 
      alert('Username was not found!')
    })
  
  } else {
  
    alert('The username is invalid!')
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img src="" id="photoReturn">

<br><br>

<input type="text" id="usernameInput">

<button onclick="getPhoto($('#usernameInput').val().trim())">Get profile photo</button>
```

Comment: Question was tagged with Java and Android, this is HTML and Javascript

Comment: This won't work because of CORS issue.

Comment: It is not giving me data if I am not logged into Instagram

Answer (score 0):

Using the [Instagram API users endpoint](https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/#get_users) (`https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{user-id}/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN` ) you will receive a response like this one:

```
{
    "data": {
        "id": "1574083",
        "username": "snoopdogg",
        "full_name": "Snoop Dogg",
        "profile_picture": "http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/profiles/profile_1574083_75sq_1295469061.jpg",
        "bio": "This is my bio",
        "website": "http://snoopdogg.com",
        "counts": {
            "media": 1320,
            "follows": 420,
            "followed_by": 3410
        }
}
```

Using this you can get the profile picture.

Comment: And how to get user id from User Name ?

Comment: Easily Get USER ID and User Details using this: 

`https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?q=[ USER NAME ]&client_id=[ YOU APP Client ID ]` for an example :



`https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?q=isharamadhawa&client_id=[enter your id]`

Comment: Do you have a client_id?

Comment: Yes I have Client ID and Access Tocken

Comment: "error_message": "The access_token provided is invalid."

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37609974/instagram-api-the-access-token-provided-is-invalid)

Comment: I have added public content scope while getting token and its in Sandbox mode

Comment: You should post another Question regarding your specific issue. I think you have received an answer for what you have posted here.

Comment: Blocked by cors

Comment: @IsharaMadhawa This answer is no longer accurate since this API no longer provides `full_name` or `profile_picture` fields as per https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/reference/user. The link to the API in the answer is also dead.