# How to get Instagram user profile without using the API

Tags: go, instagram, instagram-api

I am looking for a way to get the profile link of an Instagram user. My app is written in Go and gets data from hashtag instagram API. From this endpoint I know only username and got parmalink but cannot get user profile picture. I think it might be related to the token limit to use the API service to get user data.

I tried many ways to get this information but I got some problems.

1. Get request data from `https://www.instagram.com/{user-name}/` and scape with goscaper but after some time Instagram redirects to the login page.
2. Get request data from `https://www.instagram.com/{user-name}/?__a=1` got the same problem, Instagram redirects to login. Any way to avoid being redirected ?
3. Get request from permalink but goscaper cannot scape profile link user for me

Anyone has an idea?

Comment: Isn't a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50086945/how-to-get-instagram-profile-picture?

Comment: @Kangur Thank you but 

- https://www.instagram.com/USERNAME/?__a=1 this link is work but sometime they redirect link to login page.

- https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/users/USER_ID/info/ this link I can't use it. I put user id of instagram but response is not found :(

Comment: Are there any error codes along redirect? If you're not using API, but calling pages directly, then it might be that Instagram servers do block you after some requests.