# how to fetch Instagram user profile picture via API

Tags: json, api, instagram, instagram-api

I'm trying to fetch the Instagram user profile picture. I found an API to achieve this task

[https://www.instagram.com/{username}/?__a=1](https://www.instagram.com/%7Busername%7D/?__a=1)

but the above API only works when I'm logged into my account, else it wouldn't return the JSON response

Is there any workaround for this? Lots of websites are doing this, so I'm sure there is some way to do it

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Hello, did you find a solution on this problem ?

Answer (score -4):

Your Question is a [Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50086945/how-to-get-instagram-profile-picture-via-api).

I was able to try both urls and worked well.

- https://www.instagram.com/USERNAME/?__a=1
- https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/users/USER_ID/info/

Tried first one on Chrome and second one on Insomnia (both not logged on Instagram).

Comment: The duplicate question you’re referring is 4 years old. I did go through other questions before opening this one

Comment: Don’t know how it is working on your end! But on my end, it’s still asking for login