# Instagram access-token is not working with graph API

Tags: python, api, http, instagram

I am trying to get list of all posts/medias posted by user on instagram. (I bassicaly don't care how I will do that, so if you have other solution (not fixing that described in this question) I'd be grateful) I used this python code:

```
access_token = "XXXXXYU3EwVG10b1FaaWVMZAERXRkdIei15cjdoXXXXXGgxUnR4V2hyazh6ZAGVIdFNWcHg2aklSdWZAUUnNtLW03Vzd5aENDY3BlWl92dC1DRVXXXXXEyWHB3RUY0N0pMSkRHbTZAjZAVVWSVNYWmt2QmpWTXXXXX"
url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v7.0/17841405822304914/media?access_token=' + str(access_token)
r = requests.get(url)
print(r)
print(r.text)
```

Which throws following output:

```
<Response [400]>
{"error":{"message":"Invalid OAuth access token.","type":"OAuthException","code":190,"fbtrace_id":"AUp8Al-lOeDSS42uzm9mgoR"}}
```

I checked this[image: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/] - [link](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/), and it shows that I acctualy have access to user_media using this key.

Here's how I obtained my access key - [image]. I tried regenerating token, but it still refuses to work. I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37609974/instagram-api-the-access-token-provided-is-invalid), but answers didn't work for me, I also feel like it's related to old, non-graph Instagram API.